# C++ Reverse sequence of elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Hello I'm still new to C++ and I am writing a program to reverse the elements in a vector. I don't get any errors running the program but when I run it and I enter the numbers my program prints " Printing ... end of print" then it just closes on its own. I sure it may be a simple mistake.

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> reverse_a(const vector<int>&veca)
{   
vector<int> vecb;
//size_t as the index type 
size_t i = veca.size();
while ( i > 0 )
    vecb.push_back(veca[--i]); 
return vecb;
}

void print(const vector<int> vec)
{
     cout << "printing " << endl;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
         cout << vec[i] << ",";
     cout << "\n" << "\n end of print.\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<int>veca;
    vector<int>vecb;
    int input;
    while(cin >> input)
              veca.push_back(input);

    reverse_a(veca);
    print(vecb);

}
```

Comment: Why not just use [`std::vector`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) `reverse_iterator`?

Comment: `reverse_a` returned a lovely reversed vector and you threw it away. try `vecb =  reverse_a(veca);`

Comment: You can replace `reverse_a` with `vector<int> vecb(veca.rbegin(), veca.rend());`

Comment: I seen similar post to mine and I see people mention reverse_iterator but I only using what we've learned in class.  Sorry I'm still new to C++ and programming in general.

Comment: Best time to learn, GeoDeeZay. It takes longer to learn when you already know everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a simple mistake. You are forgetting to set `vecb` to the result of the `reverse_a` function in `main`. Instead of `reverse_a(veca);`, you should have `vecb = reverse_a(veca);`. The way you currently have it, `vecb` never gets set and therefore has a length of zero and nothing prints.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of off topic, but can't be explained in a comment. Aderis's answer is correct and πάντα ῥεῖ brings up an alternative for OP.

As with most intro to programming problems, the standard Library has done all of the work already. There is no need for any function because it already exists, in a somewhat twisted form:

```
std::copy(veca.rbegin(), veca.rend(), std::back_inserter(vecb));
```

[`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) does just what it sounds like it does: it copies. You specify where to start, where to stop, and where to put the results.

In this case we want to copy from `veca`, but we want to copy backwards, so rather than calling [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) like we normally would, we call [`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) to get one of those reverse iterator thingys πάντα ῥεῖ was talking about. To define the end, we use [`rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend) which, rather than tearing things limb from limb marks the end of the reverse range of veca. Typically this is one before the beginning, `veca[-1]`, if such a thing existed.

[`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) tells `std::copy` how to place the the data from `veca` in `vecb`, at the back.

One could be tempted to skip all of this reverse nonsense and

```
std::copy(veca.begin(), veca.end(), std::front_inserter(vecb));
```

but no. For one thing, it would be hilariously slow. Consider `veca = {1,2,3,4,5}`.  You'd insert 1 at the beginning of `vecb`, then copy it to the second slot to make room for 2. Then move 2 and 1 over one slot each to fit in 3. You'd get the nice reverse ordering, but the shuffling would be be murderous. The second reason you can't do it is because vector does not implement the `push_front` function required to make this work, again because it would be brutally slow.

Caveat:
This approach is simple, but slow. The back_inserter may force resizing of the vector's internal array, but this can be mitigated by preallocating `vecb`'s storage.